# How to check if a property is virtual with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, virtual

Given an object, how can I tell if that object has virtual properties?

```
var entity = repository.GetByID(entityId);
```

I tried looking in:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
```

But couldn't discern if any of the properties would indicate virtual.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsVirtual).ToArray();
```

Or, for .NET 4 and below:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual).ToArray();
```

That will get a list of public virtual properties.

It won't work for write-only properties. If it needs to, you can check `CanRead` and `CanWrite` manually, and read the appropriate method.

For example:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => (p.CanRead ? p.GetMethod : p.SetMethod).IsVirtual).ToArray();
```

You could also just grab the first accessor:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual).ToArray();
```

Comment: To safely handle private properties you can do:
`(p.CanRead ? p.GetGetMethod(true) : p.GetSetMethod(true)).IsVirtual;`

Answer (score 22):

Checking only `IsVirtual` of property's accessor will give you also interface properties that are not declared `virtual` in your class. If by "virtual properties" you mean properties that you can override in derived class you should also check `IsFinal` (sealed):

```
var accessor = typeof(MyType).GetProperty("MyProp").GetAccessors()[0];
var isVirtual = accessor.IsVirtual && ! accessor.IsFinal;
```

Check this sample app:

```
using System;

namespace VirtualPropertyReflection
{
    interface I
    {
        int P1 { get; set; }
        int P2 { get; set; }
    }

    class A : I
    {
        public int P1 { get; set; }
        public virtual int P2 { get; set; }

        static void Main()
        {
            var p1accessor = typeof(A).GetProperty("P1").GetAccessors()[0];
            Console.WriteLine(p1accessor.IsVirtual); // True
            Console.WriteLine(p1accessor.IsFinal); // True

            var p2accessor = typeof(A).GetProperty("P2").GetAccessors()[0];
            Console.WriteLine(p2accessor.IsVirtual); // True
            Console.WriteLine(p2accessor.IsFinal); // False
        }
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4793253/633721).

Comment: Thanks for this, lots of other answers talked about `isVirtual` but the combined `isFinal` check did it for me.

Answer (score 8):

try with

```
typeof(YourClass).GetProperty("YouProperty").GetGetMethod().IsVirtual;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the GetAccessors method, for example for the first property:

Get accessor:

```
properties[0].GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual
```

Set accessor:

```
properties[0].GetAccessors()[1].IsVirtual
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky, because a property can be read-only, write-only, or read/write. Therefore, you need to check both underlying methods for being virtual, like this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = ...
var isVirtual = (pi.CanRead && pi.GetMethod.IsVirtual)
             || (pi.CanWrite && pi.SetMethod.IsVirtual);
```

Answer (score 0):

IsVirtual alone didn't work for me. It was telling me that all my non-virtual non-nullable properties were virtual. I had to use a combination of IsFinal and IsVirtual

Here's what I ended up with:

```
PropertyInfo[] nonVirtualProperties = myType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetAccessors()[0].IsFinal || !x.GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual).ToArray();

PropertyInfo[] virtualProperties = myType.GetProperties().Where(x => !x.GetAccessors()[0].IsFinal && x.GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual).ToArray();
```