# using reflection to get properties of class inheriting an interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following scenario where I would like to get the properties of a class which implements an interface, however excluding those properties which are virtual. Just to make things clear I am going to give you a small example:-

Imagine we have the following Interface:-

```
public interface IUser
{
    int UserID { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

A class which implements this interface:-

```
public class User: IUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual int GUID { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is get the properties of the class excluding the virtual. When the class does not implement the interface the following works just fine:-

```
var entityProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties()
                                   .Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsVirtual == false);
```

However, when the interface is implemented, the above line of code will not return any results. If I remove the 'where' it works fine (however the virtual property won't get excluded) like the below:

```
var entityProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties();
```

Someone has got any idea please? I searched however I was not able to find any results. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you check this post: [How to check if a property is virtual with reflection?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305945/how-to-check-if-a-property-is-virtual-with-reflection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you want [`IsFinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isfinal(v=vs.110).aspx):

> To determine if a method is overridable, it is not sufficient to check that IsVirtual is true. For a method to be overridable, IsVirtual must be true and IsFinal must be false. For example, a method might be non-virtual, but it implements an interface method.

So:

```
var entityProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties()
                                   .Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsFinal);
```

Or possibly:

```
var entityProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties()
                                   .Where(p => !p.GetMethod.IsVirtual ||
                                               p.GetMethod.IsFinal);
```

Comment: The indentation of the last line is messing with my OCD!

Comment: _"I have the following scenario where I would like to get the properties of a class which implements an interface, however excluding those properties which are virtual."_. I thought to be or not virtual here is a _side_ detail (even if it occupies most of space in OP question).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I believe the OP is interested in properties which are not being *declared* as `virtual`. Think of the C# keyword "virtual" as having two meanings: a) overridable; b) virtual.

Comment: Yes, probably I thought he was looking for properties IMPLEMENTED because of the interface (excluding those that are still overridable, excluding - for example - GUID both because virtual and because it's not in IUser). Good catch!