# C# AutoMapper ,Change Mapper Setting on Fly

Tags: c#, automapper, bson

This is my Domain Object Type

```
[Table("CredentialingCallDetail")]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class CredentialingCallDetail : FullAuditedEntity<ObjectId>
{ 
    public string RepresentativeName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneExtension { get; set; }
    public string CallResultStatus { get; set; }
    public string IsFacilityCredentialed { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public List<LicensedProfessionalCredentialed> LicensedProfessionalCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Data Transfer Objet

```
[AutoMapTo(typeof(CredentialingCallDetail))]
public class CreateCredentialingCallDetailInput
{    
    [BsonIgnore]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RepresentativeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneExtension { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CallResultStatus { get; set; }
    public string IsFacilityCredentialed { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public string Status  { get; set; }
    public List<LicensedProfessionalCredentialedDto> LicensedProfessionalCredentials { get; set; }
    public CreateCredentialingCallDetailInput()
    {
        LicensedProfessionalCredentials = new List<LicensedProfessionalCredentialedDto>();
    }
}
```

When I map `CreateCredentialingCallDetailInput`  to `CredentialingCallDetail`  i.e

```
CredentialingCallDetail newCredentialingCallDetail = input.CredentialingCallDetail.MapTo<CredentialingCallDetail>();
```

I get the exception 
[image]

There is a mismatch between the type of Id , Automapper is not mapping string to ObjectId,Is There any way i can change the setting on fly , i.e change setting to ignore Id Mapping ?

Comment: With newer versions of AM you can create multiple mapping profiles instead of the static singleton mapping it had before. Just create another profile and use in your mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28382811/3105612) question (yes question!).
You can do this in two ways.Check the question for details.

Quick answer for you.

You can ignore extra elements when defining mapping.

```
 CreateMap<CreateCredentialingCallDetailInput, CredentialingCallDetail >()
.ForSourceMember(src => src.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Just add 2nd line to your existing mapping.

This looks ambiguous,

```
CredentialingCallDetail newCredentialingCallDetail =
input.CredentialingCallDetail.MapTo<CredentialingCallDetail>();
```

Should not it be something like this

```
CredentialingCallDetail newCredentialingCallDetail =
CreateCredentialingCallDetailInput.MapTo<CredentialingCallDetail>();
```