# Automapper how to use IgnoreMap attribute with MemberList.Source option

Tags: c#, automapper

How to use attribute-based member ignoring (e.g. `[IgnoreMap]`) in conjunction with the `MemberList.Source` option in Automapper 9.0? The IgnoreMap attribute seems to be ...ignored - the following example throws:

```
public class Source
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    [IgnoreMap]
    public string IgnoredProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>(MemberList.Source);
    }
}
```

when configuring using the `MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`. It throws AssertConfigurationIsValid as if `[IgnoreMap]` was not there:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ================================================================== Source -> Destination (Source member list) Mapping.Source ->
>   Mapping.Destination (Source member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: IgnoredProperty

I have also tried `[Ignore]` `[NotMapped]` attributes, however the result was the same.

Comment: `[IgnoreMap]` does not work with source validation.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu is that documented behavior and if so, do they specify an alternative?

Comment: You have to do it in code, there is no attribute for that. Of course you can always implement that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

i havent tried attribute ignore for automapper, i always use this

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>.ForMember(x => x.IgnoredProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

or try answers here : [How to configure Automapper to automatically ignore properties with ReadOnly attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382811/how-to-configure-automapper-to-automatically-ignore-properties-with-readonly-att)

Comment: Thanks, but this cannot work - `IgnoredProperty` is not a member of `Destination` class.

Comment: @wondra then you can switch which property should the `IgnoredProperty` should be handled

Comment: I think we misunderstood eachother, the `x` in you example is of `Destination` Type, not a `Source` Type. Clearly `x` cannot be used to ignore the `Source.IgnoredProperty` property, or in other words: the sample would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Additional properties in source automatically ignored by mapper ,so you should ignore explicitly ignored properties of destination, so in your case you must do like below code:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>.ForMember(x => x.PropertyC , options => options.Ignore());
```

Comment: `PropertyC` is not the one to be ignored, Automapper complains about `IgnoredProperty` property.