# How to exclude all virtual properties from classes inheritted from ClassMapper<T> by default?

Tags: c#, mapping, dapper, dapper-extensions

I have a lot of POCO classes that contain several virtual properties each. Something like this:

```
public class Policy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity Entity{ get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

To make `Dapper.Extensions` work, I need to write a mapping for each of these classes, which is fine. My problem is, if there are any `virtual` properties inside a class, they need to be explicitly marked as **ignored**, which I always forget to do.

```
public sealed class PolicyMapper : BaseMapper<Policy>
{
    public PolicyMapper()
    {
        Map(p => p.Entity).Ignore();
        Map(p => p.Program).Ignore();
        Map(p => p.Transactions).Ignore();
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

What would be great for me, if the `Dapper.Extensions` library will automatically exclude virtual properties, if any, when mapped to the POCO class. There is an extension for `Automapper` that does something similar ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24597862/4383585)). Is there a way to do that for `Dapper.Extensions` library? Possibly something like this:

```
public sealed class PolicyMapper : BaseMapper<Policy>
{
    public PolicyMapper()
    {
        IgnoreAllVirtual();
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. Since all my mapping classes derive from BaseMapper class, I decided to override AutoMap() method that will exclude virtual properties:

```
public class BaseMapper<T> : ClassMapper<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public BaseMapper()
    {

    }

    protected override void AutoMap()
    {
        CustomAutoMap(null);
    }

    private void CustomAutoMap(Func<Type, PropertyInfo, bool> canMap)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        bool hasDefinedKey = Properties.Any(p => p.KeyType != KeyType.NotAKey);
        PropertyMap keyMap = null;

        foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            // Exclude virtual properties
            if (propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Properties.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ((canMap != null && !canMap(type, propertyInfo)))
            {
                continue;
            }

            PropertyMap map = Map(propertyInfo);
            if (!hasDefinedKey)
            {
                if (string.Equals(map.PropertyInfo.Name, "id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    keyMap = map;
                }

                if (keyMap == null && map.PropertyInfo.Name.EndsWith("id", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    keyMap = map;
                }
            }
        }

        if (keyMap != null)
        {
            keyMap.Key(PropertyTypeKeyTypeMapping.ContainsKey(keyMap.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
                ? PropertyTypeKeyTypeMapping[keyMap.PropertyInfo.PropertyType]
                : KeyType.Assigned);
        }
    }
}
```

}