# How can add an attribute to all same property of different models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Consider below code:

```
namespace Domain.Models;

public partial class Class1
{
    //Other properties

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
public partial class Class2
{
    //Other properties

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

adding `[IgnoreDataMember]` to `public virtual ICollection<...>` in each class, is a repetitive task (Consider the large number of these repetitive tasks in a large project)!

Is there any clean solution that works like this proposition: "Add `[IgnoreDataMember]` to all `virtual ICollection` properties"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use VScode and use edit-"replace in files" function. Just note that visual studio cannot replace with multiple line.
[image: ![enter image description here]

And in case you add depulicate attribute. You can then replace the double attribute to one.
[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I agree that this is the way to do it, but i disagree with the 'cannot replace with multiple line' statement. It is possible to do so by using Regex ( .* Icon)

Comment: @Xavjer I think you are right. Regex could be a better solution because different spaces width may cannot be recognized by this simple replace.

Comment: I think for the question, the normal replace will work best as long as everything is 'private virtual ICollection.....', maybe a reformat will be necessary for the indentation but I would prefer to do it this way and omit having to write a Regex just to have the spaces correct afterwards :)

Comment: @QiangFu Thanks for you answer. It's a solution, but I want to implement it in Code. e.g. a setting in startup that says: "ignore all virtual ICollection data members". because base on you solution, after adding new model, I should replace it or add that attribute one another time(It's also a repetitive task)!

Comment: @nimaansari Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597120/how-to-ignore-all-properties-that-are-marked-as-virtual